# Downvoted answers stay grayed-out when hovered over

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Answers downvoted to -3 or less are shown grayed out, but [they're supposed to unfade when you hover the mouse over them.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129593/un-fade-low-score-answers-on-rollover-or-click)  Except it doesn't work here on RPG.SE.  (It does work on most other SE sites.)

Please fix this, o' great CSS wizards of SE.

Comment: @doppelgreener: That's strange. You're not using [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup), are you? (SOUP v1.30 still has a client-side fix that makes this work on all SE sites. I removed it from the v1.31 devel branch because I thought it was no longer needed, but apparently there are still some issues left.)

Comment: I am! I forgot! I disabled it and yep it's totally broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next deploy (usually several times a day)